# How to remove rows below a certain row number phpexcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I would like to remove the bottom records. When I reach row 6 anything below that I would like to remove in phpexcel.

```
for($tot=2; $tot<$highestRowEMDist; $tot++){
  $chkven = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('C'.$tot)->getValue();
  if ($chkven!="Test" ) {
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->removeRow(7,0);
  }
}
```

All I want is if I reach row 6 anything below that needs to be deleted

Comment: I it getting to this part of the code?
`if ($chkven!="Test" ) {
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->removeRow(7,0);
}`
Maybe put an echo in the if statement to check if it is even reaching the remove function?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution

```
for($row=2; $row < $highestRowEMDist; $row++){
   $value = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('C'.$row)->getValue();
   if ($value != "Quest") {
      $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->removeRow($row, $row);
   }
}
```